# Embed error setTitle cannot read property null

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to create embeds following the guide on discord.js but after writing the code properly, while executing that embed command it gives an error in terminal.

this bot is still need a huge amount of implementations but code just gives error which are a little weird as the implementation seems to be correct

currently dealing with embeds

i need help , please

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("embed")
    .setDescription("Returns an Embed"),
    async execute(interaction,client){
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')
        .setTitle('This is totally an embed')
        .setDescription('This might Work ? Maybe')
        .setColor(0x18e1ee)
        .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp(Date.now())
        .setAuthor({
            url: `https://ww4.gogoanimes.org/`,
            iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
            name: interaction.user.tag
        })
        .setFooter({
            iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
            text: client.user.tag
        })
        .setURL('https://discord.gg/kMb9XZAq')
        .addFields([
            {
                name: 'Field 1',
                value: 'Field value 1',
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: `Field 2`,
                value: `Field value 2`,
                inline: true
            }
        ]);
        await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    },
}
```

and the error i get in the terminal is : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAox0.png)

i just want that embed code to work well, so that i can use it's good UI on all different commands

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Clearly a typo. `const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')` is shoved between `const embed = new EmbedBuilder()` and `.setTitle('This is totally an embed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the title of `null`, but it has to be an `EmbedBuilder()`. This is very easy to fix.

```
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target') // This line should not be here
        .setTitle('This is totally an embed')
        .setDescription('This might Work ? Maybe')
        // ...
```

Should become:

```
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('This is totally an embed')
        .setDescription('This might Work ? Maybe')
        // ...
```

Here we move the `const user = ...` line above so `.setTitle()` actually sets the title of the `EmbedBuilder()`. Here's a different way to see it:

Before:

```
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target').setTitle('This is totally an embed')
```

After:

```
const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle('This is totally an embed')
```

Answer (score 0):

After you initialize the embed, you initialize another variable. You should initialize the user variable first and then the embed.

```
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('This is totally an embed')
            .setDescription('This might Work ? Maybe')
            .setColor(0x18e1ee)
            .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp(Date.now())
            .setAuthor({
                url: `https://ww4.gogoanimes.org/`,
                iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
                name: interaction.user.tag
            })
            .setFooter({
                iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
                text: client.user.tag
            })
            .setURL('https://discord.gg/kMb9XZAq')
            .addFields([
                {
                    name: 'Field 1',
                    value: 'Field value 1',
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: `Field 2`,
                    value: `Field value 2`,
                    inline: true
                }
            ]);
```

Hope it helps